# Minimum cluster deployment for HA in Apache Artemis?

Tags: activemq-artemis

My application uses the following ActiveMQ Artemis cluster configuration as I need minimum number of nodes and HA.

- 1 master
- 1 slave

Is this right cluster configs for production system? If not what you recommend?

### Update

In above cluster when master fails we loose HA. Therefore I thought of having 2 slaves.

- 1 master
- 2 slaves

For split brain i found following documents helps

> Specifically, the backup will become active when it loses connection
>   to its live server. This can be problematic because this can also
>   happen because of a temporary network problem. In order to address
>   this issue, the backup will try to determine whether it still can
>   connect to the other servers in the cluster. If it can connect to more
>   than half the servers, it will become active, if more than half the
>   servers also disappeared with the live, the backup will wait and try
>   reconnecting with the live. This avoids a split brain situation.
>   https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.0.0/ha.html

Would above documentation means when i have temp network failure between master and slave , slave will check for reachability of other slave before promoting to master , thus mitigating split brain ?

Comment: Are you using replication or shared storage?

Comment: I am using replication. For split brain i intend to use Network Pinger but don't know how effective it is to avoid split brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using *replication* then the minimum number of recommended nodes to mitigate split-brain is 6. Three lives to establish a proper quorum and three corresponding backups. Keep in mind that only the *live* nodes participate in quorum voting so have 1 live and 2 backups won't help with mitigating split-brain in the case of temporary network failures.

If you're using *shared-storage* then the minimum number of recommended nodes to mitigate split-brain is 2. Just one live and one backup. This is because the file-lock on the file-system (e.g. SAN or NAS) mitigates against split-brain.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In case of 1 live and 2 backup, would network pinger ( used with LB ip address ) mitigate split brain ?

Comment: The network pinger *can* be used to mitigate split-brain, but it can be tricky to configure. You'll need to perform your own testing to ensure it works the way you want.