# ActiveMQ Artemis - is a master/slave/slave three-node configuration possible?

Tags: high-availability, activemq-artemis

For an ActiveMQ Artemis HA solution, I'm thinking that instead of using a using a primary/secondary configuration with a Zookeeper monitoring node, perhaps as master/slave/slave configuration would be better. The reason is that, as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74745127/activemq-artemis-high-availability-how-to-set-up-in-two-nodes-assuming-limite), having a single Zookeeper node is an architectural weakness. The master-slave-slave approach would at least probably have at least one node running at any given time.

Also, I'm wondering if it might be better to ask these question over the mailing list or the slack channel? Any preference there?

Comment: The preference for which or support channel to use is really up to you. Each option has unique characteristics. The mailing list probably has the widest audience of experts. Slack is good for more interactive conversations. Stack Overflow works well as a reference platform with clear answers to specific questions (which can sometimes be hard to nail down on a mailing list or in chat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a primary/backup/backup triplet is possible, but it provides no mitigation against split brain since only primary nodes participate in quorum voting. Therefore, the architectural weakness in this configuration is *significantly* worse than just have a single ZooKeeper node because with a single ZooKeeper node at least you have a *chance* of mitigating split brain whereas otherwise you don't.

Also, fail-back only works for a primary/backup pair. It doesn't work for a primary/backup/backup triplet. This is because a backup server is owned by only one primary server. This means that when the 3 broker instances are started there will be 1 primary/backup pair and a "left-over" backup which will be in a kind of idle state waiting to attach to a primary broker without a backup. Then if the primary broker fails the primary broker's backup will take over and become primary and the other backup will now become the backup of the server which just became primary. Once the broker instance which failed is restarted it will attempt to register itself as a backup of the now-primary broker and initiate fail-back. However, since the now-primary broker already has a backup it will reject the registration message from the original primary because it already has a backup, and therefore fail-back will not occur.

Comment: I guess the same happens with Classic Master/Slave/Slave also. Right?
Is there no way where I can have one primary and n slaves? 
In this [section of the doc](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#high-availability-and-failover), the first line says we can have it

Comment: ActiveMQ Classic doesn't support replication or fail-back. It only supports shared store.

Comment: As noted in the answer, you _can_ have one primary and n backups but fail-back won't work. Furthermore, if you're using replication then you won't have any mitigation against split-brain.